# Passing Facebook variables to Tab android

Tags: java, javascript, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to know if there's a way to get and pass FBUSER and FBID to each of my tab bars, and use them in every web view by passing them in the url, because I need to use them in my web views. 
Here is the code:

```
public class SampleFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";
    private WebView myWebView;
    private String LOG_TAG = "AndroidWebViewActivity";

    private int position;


    public static SampleFragment newInstance(int position) {
        SampleFragment f = new SampleFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(page, container, false);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabButton);
        final ProgressBarCircular progressBarCircular = (ProgressBarCircular) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress);

        Log.i("ADebugTag", "Value: ");


        final WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);



        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);

        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);


        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.setInitialScale(0);

        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        // If using in a fragment
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        // Other app specific specialization

        CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {

                                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                                String firstName = profile.getFirstName();
                                String a = "a";

                                Log.i("ADebugTag", "Value: " + firstName);

                            }
                        });

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.i("ADebugTag", "BANANA ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                Log.i("ADebugTag", "BOOH ");
            }
        });





        switch (position) {
            case 0:

                fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/eventiresponsive.html");
                    }
                });

            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/eventiresponsive.html");

                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        progressBarCircular.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
                loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                break;
            case 1:
                fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/fotostream.html");
                    }
                });


                loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/fotostream.html");

                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        progressBarCircular.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });


                break;
            case 2:
                fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/eventiresponsive.html");
                    }
                });


                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        progressBarCircular.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });

                loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

                break;
            case 3:
                fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
        }

        return rootView;
    }
    @Override

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that simply getting these variables can be quite tricky because they're always nested in callback methods.

What I do is store them in SharedPreferences, and then I get them easily in another part of the app.

To write more elegant and more importantly safe/efficient code, you can look up event bus (like Otto, EventBus) or Observables (RxJava) which can handle sending these objects asynchronously very easily !

Hope I helped you :).

Comment: can you make me an example for the above code? please @mehdi

Comment: It's pretty straightforward, you just have to store the strings in SharedPrefs, and then get them somewhere else.

Comment: yes, but i'm newer in Android programming and i don't know how to do it. @mehdi

Comment: ok, now there's another problem, why the var Firstname when i run isn't written in log? @mehdi

Comment: That's weird. The API must be not working properly.
If you found my answer helpful, can you set it ? Thank you :)